# Can someone provide me a sample script for a google form to auto fill the question description with the prior response?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to have the last response to a question listed as the description of the question.
I am using google forms for collecting readings from hour totalizers in a factory.  The worker collects the data by walking to each meter and records the current reading.  I want them to be able to see the reading from the prior check so they can compare.
Is this possible?

Comment: You could definitely do it with a webApp, but dheck the Google Forms Addons...There seems to be an addon named Dynamic Fields.  I've never used it but it sounds like it might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link a script to your Form and put the following code in there:

```
function formSubmitted(e) {
  var responsesObj = e.response;
  var responsesList = responsesObj.getItemResponses();

  for(var i=0; i<responsesList.length; i++) {
    var responseObj = responsesList[i];
    var responseText = responseObj.getResponse();
    var question = responseObj.getItem();
    question.setHelpText(responseText);
  }
}
```

Then, you can manually set a Form submit trigger [1] so when a response to the form is sent it'll run the formSubmitted function with the Event Object [2]. From that object you can get the FormResponse object and make the manipulations you need to your form using the Forms Service functions [3].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app

Comment: Thanks!  I will give this a try.  Im pretty new at this stuff but can usually figure it out.  I may hit you up for some help with the trigger setup.

Comment: I copied code into the script editor on my form.  It doesn't seem to be working because of needing more information.  When I run it from the editor screen I get the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property "response" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")"   -I'm sure it's because I need to link it somehow but I am not sure where to put the name or range of the response sheet it is pulling from.

Comment: You can't run it from the editor, it'll run automatically when a form response is submitted after you set the trigger "On form submit" to the formSubmitted function: Check "Managing triggers manually" here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thanks again so much for help!  I got it to work but it is only entering the prior response into the helptext section of the first question.  I have a total of 87 questions.  Where in the code would I put this information?

Comment: I edited the code in the answer so It does the same for all the questions.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks so much for providing a me with a useful solution and the informative reference links.